# Limiting comments to a certain time period in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have the ability to allow users to select a time (i.e. 5hours), when they create a post,and when the time passes the post becomes uncommentable. So after 5 hours you can't comment on that post anymore.

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible, and if it is I would like to know where should I start looking, is this a thing that ca be done by a gem or Rails can't do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define how long the Post should be commentable:

```
# in your model/post.rb
COMMENTABLE_TIME_PERIOD = 5.hours

def commentable?
  Time.current < created_at + COMMENTABLE_TIME_PERIOD
end
```

Add something to your view to hide the comment form, when the post is not commentable anymore:

```
<% unless post.commentable? %>
  your form
<% end %>
```

Add a custom validator to ensure that comment cannot be created after that period:

```
# in your model/comment.rb
validates :post_commentable

private
def post_commentable
  unless post.commentable?
    errors.add(:base, "You cannot comment on old posts")
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow this is sweet. Exactly what I was looking for! Now I just need to figure out a way in which I can allow the users to modify that time period :)

Comment: Instead of using a constant in your model, add a field to your Post model which stores the value (as I showed in my answer). Then you can let the user choose.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `commentable_until` datetime attribute in your Post model.

In the controller in which you save comments, run a check to see if that time has passed or not. If it has, don't save the comment and redirect accordingly.

You can also do this check in the view to prevent an "Add a comment" option from even appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be code style. Please write it according to your application.

```
<% ((if Time.now - @post.created_at)/ 3600) < 5 %>
<%= You can comment here %>
<% else %>
<%= You can not comment here %>
<% end %>
```